# Split string into substrings based on the separator from the left

Tags: c#, string, split

In c#, is there an elegant way to split a string like "a.b.c" into a, a.b, a.b.c 
The number of separators are not fixed so it could be "a.b" which will output {a, a.b} or "a.b.c.d" which will output {a, a.b, a.b.c, a.b.c.d}.

The only thing I can think of is split the string into individual components and then concatenate it again.

This is what I have so far:

```
var fieldNames = new List<string>();
var fieldSeparator ='.';
var myString = "a.b.c.d";
var individualFields = myString.Split(fieldSeparator);
string name = "";

foreach(var fieldName in individualFields)
{
    name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? fieldName : $"{name}{fieldSeparator}{fieldName}";
    fieldNames.Add(name);
}
```

Comment: How should `"a.b.c.d"` be split?

Comment: Define "elegant". Have you tried anything? Does it work? What would you like to see changed? Show more relevant examples and show the code you already have. There are infinite ways to solve this.

Comment: "The only thing I can think of is split the string into individual components and then concatenate it again." Maybe try to do this in c#? that would work.

Comment: how in hell does `a.b.c` become `a, a.b, a.c` ? what kind of split is that ? can you explain the tough process you have to come up with this result ?

Comment: Sorry edited the question to correct the output a, a.b, a.b.c. The community is so quick in downvoting. Gosh.

Comment: I would personally simply 1 - reverse the string, 2 - store the value, 3 - find the next separator, 4 - substring to that index, 5 repeat step 2 to 4 until nothings left. and finally reverse all results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this extension?

```
public static string[] SplitCombineFirst(this string str, params string[] delimiter)
{
    string[] tokens = str.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var allCombinations = new List<string>(tokens.Length);
    for(int take = 1; take <= tokens.Length; take++)
    {
        string combination = string.Join(delimiter[0], tokens.Take(take));
        allCombinations.Add(combination);
    }
    return allCombinations.ToArray();
}
```

Call:

```
string[] result = "a.b.c".SplitCombineFirst(".");
```

Comment: Sorry my output result was bad formatted. So a.b.c becomes a, a.b, a.b.c But I get the idea of extension method. That is a great suggestion

Comment: @tryurbest: so this does not solve the question? Could you explain the rules for the split and combine logic in your question? What is with `a.c`, should that be excluded from the result?

Comment: I just edited the question to show what exactly needs to be the output. Because my output was wrong (a.b.c does not become a, a.b, a.c). The first token is not always there. Its basically (a.b.c becomes a, a.b. a.b.c) so the string is split into tokens from the left. I can't even word it better but you can understand from the output

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a classic case for recursion.

```
List<string> splitCombine(string source, string delimiter, int startIndex)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    var indx = source.IndexOf(delimiter, startIndex);
    if (indx >= 0)
    {
        if (indx > 0)
        {
            result.Add(source.Substring(0, indx));
        }
        result.AddRange(splitCombine(source, delimiter, ++indx));
    }
    else
    {
        result.Add(source);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Call:

```
var result = splitCombine("a.b.c.d.e", ".", 0);
```